# jQuery matrix input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an inputs where I want to put some value like [ [2, 4, 2] ] (to make a multiply matrix) . Now I want to read the value but not as a "[ [2, 4, 2] ]". Is there any way to do this?

```
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <form>
            <input type="text" id="first"/>
            <label  for="first">example [ [2, 4, 2] ]</label>
            <input type="text" id="second"/>
            <select id="select">
                <option value="add">Add</option>
            </select>
            <textarea></textarea>
        </form>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var select = $('#select');

     function multiplyMatrix(m1, m2) {
        var result = [];
        for(var j = 0; j < m2.length; j++) {
            result[j] = [];
            for(var k = 0; k < m1[0].length; k++) {
                var sum = 0;
                for(var i = 0; i < m1.length; i++) {
                    sum += m1[i][k] * m2[j][i];
                }
                result[j].push(sum);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    select.change(function(){
        var 
            m1 = $('#first').val(),
            m2 = $('#second').val();
            multiplyMatrix(m1, m2);
            console.log(multiplyMatrix(m1, m2));
    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `JSON.parse` to parse a `String` object into a valid JavaScript Object ( an `array` of `array` in your case.)

When you get the values from the html nodes, you just need to parse them.

```
var m1 = JSON.parse($('#first').val()),
    m2 = JSON.parse($('#first').val());
```

You might want to validate the format of the value beforehand or put that inside of a `try {} catch (e) {}` block as it will generate an error if the value is not valid JSON.